# Volume of Rectangular solid from surface area

Tags: volume, surfaces, solid-geometry

I have a cuboid whose surface area is:
$S=73.16 cm^2$.

Also, I have the separate surface areas for the specific sides of the cuboid:

- $ab=8.41 cm^2$
- $ac=12.96 cm^2$
- $bc=15.21 cm^2$

How can one calculate the Volume of this cuboid?

Comment: The volume is $abc$. What is the product of the $3$ separate surface areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide the first two you can solve the result for $b$, then plug into the last, giving you $c$ and you are on your way.  You have three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: I don't understand the 'If you divide first two' part

Comment: I was suggesting dividing the first two equations.  That eliminates $a$ from the result and leaves you with two equations in the unknowns $b,c$.

Comment: $b = \sqrt{{ab \over ac}\,bc}$.

Comment: There is a much, much shorter way to find the volume. See my comment above.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut:  good point.  I didn't think of it.